# How to create a setup.py that consumes a tar file

Tags: python, setup.py

Our systems people bundle source up in git and do not support pip. The git repository contains a compressed tar file. And the tar file has a setup.py within it. I figure the easiest way to expose this in my project is to add a `-e git...` line to my pip requirements.txt and add a setup.py in the root of the git repository for pip to use. The last step is how to write a setup.py that installs a tar file as a source distribution.

```
/package
    /SOURCES
        package.tar.gz
    /SPECS
        site-specific-server-installation-script
```

---

In the alternative, I could just get a setup.py that does these things:

```
cd package/SOURCES
tar xzfv package-1.0.6.tar.gz
cd package-1.0.6/
python setup.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with writing a pseudo setup.py file in the root of the git package:

```
import os
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    package_name = 'package'
    short_package_name = 'package-1.0.6'

    print "Changing to SOURCES"
    os.chdir('SOURCES')

    tar_file = '.'.join([short_package_name, 'tar', 'gz'])
    print "Untarring ", tar_file
    p = subprocess.Popen(['tar', 'xzfv', tar_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = p.communicate()

    print "Changing to ", short_package_name
    os.chdir(short_package_name)

    print "Setting up source distribution"
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'setup.py', 'install'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = p.communicate()
```

It does not use the setup API at all but relies on using the setup.py name to get invoke at install-time.

---

I am reliably informed, however, that easy_install supports installation from a tar file: 'easy_install SOURCES/source.tar.gz'. So, is there a pip `-e ...git` directive that allows pulling a git repository from git and install from a nested tar file?